# Month Title is not moving on left FSCALENDAR

Tags: ios, fscalendar

[image]

I want this *June,2018* to align at left but i didnt found any editting configuration for headerview in FSCALENDAR im using FS calender...
any one know how can we do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this. You cannot move the title to left but you can set **headerTitleTextSize** to 0 and **headerHeight** to your desired size.

I have achieved this using this method :

[image]

Put label inside the FSCalendar view and align as desired in the storyboard.[image: Like this]

Don't forget to set **headerTitleTextSize** to 0

Hope it helps !